# Shiny apps stuck in italics

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I opened some Shiny apps today and discovered that, when I run them in RStudio, every piece of text in each of the apps was in italics -- in headers, select-input menus, and even data tables. Nothing in any of the apps is supposed to be (nor ever has been) italicized. The error occurs exclusively when I run the apps locally in RStudio; everything looks normal when I run it locally in a browser or when I go to the links where they are deployed.

Nothing in the files has changed since yesterday (when they were fully functional) and my RStudio is fully updated. I updated R and all the relevant packages but it did not make a difference.

Any idea what's going on or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds incredibly bizarre. I'd recommend re-installing RStudio, and make sure you install a stable version (not one of the dailies)... Let me know if that doesn't work.